# How to build detect it easy on ubuntu 20.04 from horsicq github?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i have cloned project from this link: https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy
And i don't know what to do next, read.me says this commands : chmod a+x configure
./configure
make
make install
But it doesn't work . i want to check docs from command line for java project

Comment: Before "a+x configure" the text says `git clone --recursive https://github.com/horsicq/DIE-engine.git`

Comment: I wrote that I copied this project in the beggining

Answer (score 0):

1. **git clone --recursive https://github.com/horsicq/DIE-engine.git** "--recursive" is very important. It clones all module
2. **chmod a+x configure** It makes the file "configure" executable.
3. **./configure** "configure" checks if the system has all nessecary packages. If it fails you should install these packages.
   For Ubuntu: **sudo apt-get install --quiet --assume-yes build-essential qt5-default qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtscript5-dev**
4. **make** It compiles the project
5. **sudo make install** It installs the program to system

Comment: Thanks ,but i tried to make Debian commands(which were higher in instruction) , and it's works in Linux !!!